# Yii2, create a query with array input

Tags: php, yii2

I have a query in yii2:

```
$models = Company::find()->where('name like :q', ['q'=>/* Array here */])->all();
```

You can see that I have an array of q-elements I want to add to the query. How can I write the query so that it will check for one or many q elements (size of array unknown)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you realy need `LIKE` condition for your SQL statement instead of `IN` (look second answer):

```
$query = Company::find();
foreach($words as $word){
    $query->orWhere(['like','q', $word]);
}
$models = $query->all();
```

This will generate SQL staement like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE field_name LIKE '%one%'
   OR field_name LIKE '%two%'
   OR field_name LIKE '%three%'
```

Comment: This is a great solution I had never thought about.

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html, the IN condition can be used to specify multiple possibilities using the something like the following pattern:

```
$models = Company::find()->where(['q'=>$qArray])->all();
```

This will generate an SQL statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE q IN ('a','b'....);
```

assuming the contents of the `$qArray` variable is `Array('a', 'b', ...)`